# Set User Status with "@mentions" integration

Tags: api, facebook

StackOverflow'ers,

I realize the new "@mentions" is a very new feature to facebook, but can any of you think of how to access this feature using the Facebook API?

I would assume there would need to be a separate call to get a list of available users/applications/ect...

I am just brainstorming here, I realize this may not be possible yet. Any help is much appreciated.

Thanks!

Comment: the question is one year old & we still don't have a proper resolution to this problem :(

Answer (score 4, accepted):

AFAIK, This is currently not available through facebook api. 
( http://wiki.developers.facebook.com/index.php/Users.setStatus )
However you can use the following 
use the following format for tagging

```
 tagging @[USERID:blah] in my message from a app
```

where USERID is the numeric userId of the user whom you want to tag in the status and blah is any string. you should give a string there for it to work.

This format also works when you try to update the status on facebook directly. You can test it there.

Comment: I am also trying to accomplish this. So far no luck with either @[USERID:x] or adding the to parameter as in the example on http://developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/api/post

Comment: This isn't working with Open Graph API, it posts @[USERID:blah] as it is to facebook.

Comment: Just curious, what is the function of "blah" in this syntax. If it has no purpose, then why not @[USERID] instead?

Answer (score 1):

Per Colin's bugs link (http://bugs.developers.facebook.net/show_bug.cgi?id=12947), it appears the link aspect of this feature has been disabled for 3rd party apps. It will only display the tagged friend's name in plain text, without linking and without notifications.

Answer (score 0):

Also have no idea how to solve this. Anyone?

I have submitted a ticket for this here:

http://bugs.developers.facebook.net/show_bug.cgi?id=12947

Some apps are currently exposing a vulnerability within the facebook API